# Node.js sharing the same HTTP agent across service calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, keep-alive

I have a node.js backend that connects to external service via HTTP request.
I am using the [node.js HTTP](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http) to manage my requests. My question is about how to properly use Node.js http Agent with the `keep-alive` option.

The [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#new-agentoptions) explains that we should create a new Agent and pass it to the request. This is the same for all the examples I found. They all do something like this:

```
const http = require("http");

const agent = new http.Agent({
    keepAlive: true
});

const options = {
  host: 'myserver.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  agent: agent,
};
  
const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log("StatusCode: ", res.statusCode);
});
```

1. Since my agent has `keepAlive` turned on I should create only one instance of the agent, save it somewhere (static?) and reuse it everytime I do a request to that service. In other words, I should only call `new http.Agent` one time when my backend is created and keep using the same instance, otherwise I would be created a new agent for every request. Is this correct? is there a better way of keeping the agent instance other than making it global or static?
2. I don't know if I'll be able to get an answer here or better as AWS directly, but let's say my backend is a AWS lambda fucntion, how can they share Agents between invocations, as lambdas are short lived, does it even make sense to have `keepAlive` for that use case?

Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: There's a lot of questions here, but the short answer is: 1) to reuse anything, you need to keep some kind or reference to it. How you do this, is up to you. 2) Keeping a connection alive for many requests saves time, but keep in mind that if you want to also do parallel requests, you should use either HTTP2 or multiple connections.